# I have a message error about my signingSecret for slack bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, slack, bolt

I'm a begginer in development and I try to develop a slack bot with the following code:

```
const {App} = require('@slack/bolt');

const app = new App ({
    token : process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET
});

(async () => {
    await app.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);
})();
```

for my .env:

```
{
  SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = "my token",
  SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET = "my Signing Secret"
}
```

and my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev":"nodemon slack.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@slack/bolt": "^3.11.0",
}
```

but it doesn't works. I have this message:

> AppInitializationError: signingSecret is required to initialize the
> default receiver. Set signingSecret or use a custom receiver. You can
> find your Signing Secret in your Slack App Settings.

When I refer to the documentation of Slack, and after verification and code review, it seems to be the same, someone knows why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `process.env.{SOME_VARIABLE}` you are referring to your local system variable during the execution of your js script, so it means that they should be `sourced` in some way.
As it already sad `Ali Rashidi` you can use `dotenv` npm package to achieve the goal, but personally i prefer just loading them via configuration file, or even better just source your .env file in your shell before starting your script
ie:

```sh
source .env
node yourscript.js
```

Note: This approach requires a manual sourcing every time of your .env file so it's not so practical way

Instead you can try to do something like

```
// slack_configuration.json
{

   "SLACK_BOT_TOKEN": "YOUR TOKEN",
   "SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET": "YOUR SIGNING SECRET"
}
```

```js
const { App } = require('@slack/bolt');

const slackConfiguration = require('./slack_configuration.json')

const app = new App ({
    token : slackConfiguration.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    signingSecret: slackConfiguration.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET
});

(async () => {
    await app.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);
})();
```

in general this kind of approach is preferred in local machine and not in specific container designed with the purpose to only run the application, as it more secure, all you `SECRET` should not be accessed via .env as they are accessible to all process in the system so they are exposed

Answer (score 2):

You must install the `dotenv` package and use it to parse the `.env` file and load its variables.

- Install dotenv: `npm i dotenv`
- Write this at the very beginning of the program's entry file: `require('dotenv').config()`